My photos were encrypted on my phone, Galaxy S20 FE, SD card, but I had a problem with phone's fingerprints
My photos were encrypted on my phone, a Samsung Galaxy S20 FE with an SD card, but I had a problem with the fingerprint sensor which forced me to factory reset my phone. After that, I can't access any photos. It thinks that the phone has changed.
Is there a solution to make the photos known on mobile?

How did you encrypt your photos on the sd-card? As to my knowledge the S20fe doesn't support formatting/using the sd-card as internal storage (which encrypted all data o the sd-card) the only alternative is using sd-card as portable storage. And in portable mode all files are stored as the app saves them (which means by default unencrypted). Therefore your description misses the info how your images had been encrypted.

If the photos are encrypted on the SD card, then the answer is no. This is because the encryption key is the pin/password that you use to lock the phone.
You could try

Recall the pin you had used before and set the same pin.
Take the SD card out and try it on a desktop.

